# Geoserver REST api control

Tags: geoserver, rest, mapcontrol

Recently I am using Geoserver grammatically through its REST api. When I request for a map it gives me a map image.

**My request code is like this:**

```
public string GetMap(string name)
            {
                WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:8888/geoserver/wms/reflect?layers=" + name);

                using (WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse())
                {
                    FileStream imageStream;
                    using (imageStream = new FileStream(@"E:\image.png", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
                    {
                        var responseStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
                        if (responseStream != null) responseStream.CopyTo(imageStream);
                    }
                }
                return @"E:\image.png";
            }
```

It gives me an image like this:

[image]

But i need the whole control of Geoserver map like zooming or others:

[image: the whole map control]

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2):

Add &format=application/openlayers to your reflector URL, it will give you back the usual preview. 
Some docs here:
http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/tutorials/wmsreflector.html

Answer (score 0):

The image of the "whole control" is the OpenLayers client, not really GeoServer. To use openlayers (which is in Javascript), you'd need a JS interpreter.

If you want a C# control for a thick client or ASP.NET application, take a look at:

- SharpMap - https://sharpmap.codeplex.com/
- BruTile - https://brutile.codeplex.com/

Those are alternatives ways to access the WMS/WMTS/etc APIs (which is what you are really doing with your WebRequest GET, and what OpenLayers does).

Which of the C# alternatives will meet your needs depends on what you need to do (which would have been good to put in the question, perhaps next time). I'd start with SharpMap.

Comment: Thanks, I am going through your links, then I will give you feedback.

Comment: You given links are above my level, so i gave up.